# Pouchdb OAuth authentication

Tags: oauth, couchdb, pouchdb

I use couchdb 1.6, PouchDb 6.0.7 and [OAuth-1.0a.js](https://github.com/ddo/oauth-1.0a)
How can I use pouchdb OAuth authentication with couchdb?

My code is (without pouchdb):

```
  var oauth = OAuth({
    consumer: {
        key: 'example.org',
        secret: 'sekr1t'
    },
    signature_method: 'HMAC-SHA1',
    hash_function: function(base_string, key) {
return CryptoJS.HmacSHA1(base_string, key).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64);
    }
});


var request_data = {
    url: 'http://10.6.40.216:5984/patient',
    method:'GET'
};


var token = {
    key: 'token1',
    secret: 'tokensekr1t'
};



$.ajax({
    url: request_data.url,
    type: request_data.method,
    headers: oauth.toHeader(oauth.authorize(request_data, token))
}).done(function(data) {
console.log(data)
    //process your data here
});
```

Result: It works.

My code is (with pouchdb):

```
var oauth = OAuth({
    consumer: {
        key: 'example.org',
        secret: 'sekr1t'
    },
    signature_method: 'HMAC-SHA1',
    hash_function: function(base_string, key) {

return CryptoJS.HmacSHA1(base_string, key).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64);
    }
});


var request_data = {
    url: 'http://10.6.40.216:5984/patient',
    method:'GET'
};


var token = {
    key: 'token1',
    secret: 'tokensekr1t'
};

var db =new PouchDB("http://10.6.40.216:5984/patient");
var opts = {
ajax: {      
            headers:  oauth.toHeader(oauth.authorize(request_data, token))

        }
         };

         db.get("000013",opts);
```

Result: It doesn't work.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: This can not work. Oauth has to sign each request individually. You are adding the headers to the request with the static request_data. Unfortunately I am also looking for a answer.